# How to view table structure sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to make a new table like as an existing table in MySQL database with some "column name" changes. So, is there any way to see the SQL dump of the existing table without importing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE oldtable
```

Comment: @P.Salmon it's hard to say. Just reading the question, you might be right, but the title definitely suggests this is the answer.

Comment: yeah, @Nick that's helpful.